# File path not being found

Tags: php

I used this code to open the file I just created on my desktop name webdictionary.txt

But it gives me an error when I open the page and I assume it has got something to do with the path of the file.

How can I open a file that is sitting on my desktop?

Here what I tried on php.

```
<?php
    $file = fopen("webdictionary.txt","r");
    echo $file;
?>
```

Comment: You need the absolute path of the file something like "C:/Users/you/Desktop/webdictionary.txt"

Comment: You can try specifying the full path to the file. (ie. C:/users/you/desktop/file)

Comment: @Kyle Domingo. I just did it this way:C:/Users/Thulani/Desktop/webdictionary.txt. It does not show any error but the file also does not open

Comment: `fopen` returns a file handle. If you want to echo the contents, use [fread](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) or use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) instead

Comment: Appreciate the support. You are right.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the PHP locally on your computer in Windows, you require to use the full path to the file e.g.

```
<?php
    $file = readfile("C:/Users/Username/Desktop/webdictionary.txt","r");
    echo $file;
?>
```

[fread](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) can be used to get the contents of the file, see the PHP documentation on how to use it.

In the case you have uploaded the PHP code to an external server, you will need to upload the text file **to the server as well** in the same folder and then call it like you have been doing:

```
<?php
    $file = readfile("webdictionary.txt","r");
    echo $file;
?>
```

Comment: using the echo, it prints this: Resource id #3.
So for now I tested like this: echo readfile("C:/Users/Thulani/Desktop/webdictionary.txt");

Answer (score 0):

You should first check if [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) on given absolute path

```
$ touch foo/bar/lorem.txt
$ cat foo/bar/lorem.txt


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...

$ php -a
Interactive mode enabled

php > $f1 = 'foo/bar/lorem.txt';
php > $f2 = 'foo/bar/ipsum.txt';
php > function read_content_if_exists($f) {
php { if (file_exists($f)) {
php { echo fread(fopen($f, "r"), filesize($f));
php { fclose($f);
php { } else {
php { echo "file does not exist";
php { }
php { }
php > read_content_if_exists($f1);


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...

php > read_content_if_exists($f2);
file does not exist
```